# Code coverage with Functional JS Tests

Tags: testing, 9

So I am trying to get the code coverage report to work with my functional JS tests.  I have been looking everywhere and trying everything, but I just can not seem to get the report to work, even though I know my code is being touched.  The report just keeps saying 0% of code.

Here are my tests: https://git.uwaterloo.ca/ece-651-drupal-project/uw_news_profile/-/blob/1.x/tests/src/Functional/UwNewsTests.php

Here is the script I run to try and get the code coverage: https://git.uwaterloo.ca/ece-651-drupal-project/uw_news_profile/-/blob/1.x/code_coverage.sh

Here is my phpunit.xml file: https://git.uwaterloo.ca/ece-651-drupal-project/uw_news_profile/-/blob/1.x/phpunit.xml

I am using Drupal4Docker as my docker container, with xdebug3 turned on and mode set to coverage:

```
php:
    image: wodby/drupal-php:$PHP_TAG
    container_name: "${PROJECT_NAME}_php"
    environment:
      PHP_SENDMAIL_PATH: /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -S mailhog:1025
      PHP_FPM_USER: wodby
      PHP_FPM_GROUP: wodby
      PHP_XDEBUG: 1
      PHP_XDEBUG_MODE: coverage
      PHP_XDEBUG_CLIENT_HOST: 172.17.0.1 # Linux
```

Any help will be appreciated, I am doing this for my Master's degree course in Software Engineering and if I don't get code coverage working, then I will fail the project.  I have spent weeks at this with many late nights, PLEASE HELP if you can.

Comment: Is XDEBUG_CLIENT_HOST required on Linux? I had issue with XDEBUG triggering until I removed that line.

Comment: (in relation to updating to xdebug 3, that is)

Comment: I have tried it both with and without that statement. My normal xdebug in debug mode works just fine.